# Can I feed only images to simple CNN model without using label data?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have only image dataset. I want to take only feature map from simple CNN model so can i give only images to model without using label data? How to fit to madel only images?[image][image]

Comment: Simply pass it through a well known existing DL arch with a hook(in PyTorch) and extract the vecs?

Comment: Can i use kears instated of PyTorch? And Is it possible to give only images without label to DL arch in PyTorch?

Comment: No as the below answer highlights already, you can't train a DL model(except few things like AutoEncoders for finding similar things etc) without labels because there has to be a minimisation of a loss function for which you need labels..

Comment: Then what will be the labels for my change detection image dataset in my case?..i want to detect change between two pair images for that i required only feature vectors of two pair images and then find out distance map between two feature vectors..so for that i think it doesn't required any label data..so i just want to know only images is sufficient to train network using PyTorch

Answer (score 1):

To train the model, you need an objective to minimize. Very often, labels are used for this, for example, for an object recognition problem, to tell the model the kind of object in an image. You then train the CNN to encode features in the intermediate layers that are useful to solve this problem. The objective to minimize here has something to do with how often you identify the right object.

You can also train a model on an objective without labels, for example in an auto-encoder, where you use a CNN to find a representation of the input that has a lower dimension than the input, and then you typically use the same architecture but backwards to decode it back to the original input. The objective here is the similarity between the input and the output image.

A CNN trained this way, can be useful as a compression algorithm, because it encodes the image to some smaller representation in the middle layer of the auto-encoder, in such a way that you can rebuild the image to some level of accuracy.

So it's possible, but there is no reason to think that a CNN trained for an auto-encoder would be useful in an object recognition problem.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. So Can I use auto-encoder model instaed of DL arch ? And Is it required only images without label to train Auto-encoder

Comment: I think the important insight is that yes, you can train a CNN that will extract features from unlabeled images (which was how you phrased your question), but it depends on the problem you're solving, which features are important. So if you train a CNN as part of an auto-encoder, then it will train features that work well for compression, but if you want to do face recognition, it could be useless. You can use an auto-encoder if it's suitable for your problem, but you didn't say what that is. An auto-encoder can be trained with only images, no labels required.

Comment: Thanku for your valuable reply..it will help me to extend my work forward..